# Inline math: Line breaking and stretching only in specified places

Tags: math-mode, spacing, line-breaking, inline

Is it possible to have document-wide solution for all inline formulas was breakable and stretchable only in pointed positions?
Like

```
$longformula1 \/ longformula2 \/ longformula3$
```

was able to break only in points `\/` (but not be forced to break on each) and all formulas 1,2,3 had fixed unstretched size.

An example - how my document does but shouldn't look like

```
\documentclass[10pt,british,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\selectlanguage{british}

\noindent text $t:\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{F}}$ text $0\leq a\leq b$
teeeeeeeeeeext $\left\{ s_{i}\right\} :\mathcal{T_{F}^{\mathnormal{\ast|\omega}}}$
teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeext

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you can use (if possible) `${longformula1}$ ${longformula2}$ ${longformula3}$` It will break only between the sub formulas.

Comment: There's no way to make the output of your example document look nice, except hyphenating the long `teeeeeeext`.

Comment: @HendrikVogt I'm aware of it. I just tried to show, what is the problem. - Short lines + long words + inline formulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement seems a little odd, but

```
\thinmuskip=3mu
\medmuskip=4mu %plus 2mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=5mu % plus 5mu
```

will remove all default stretchability

```
\binoppenalty=10000 %700
\relpenalty=10000 %500
```

will remove all default line break possibilities

then you can use

```
\linebreak[2]
```

for some number between 0 and 4 to encourage line breaks at points where you want to allow them.

Comment: Well, I have pretty short lines, which makes half of formulas being stretched and broken, while most of them shouldn't be.

Comment: @Number47 It is probably better to set the penalties but leave the stretch and shrink so the white space in math can help the white space in text adjust to help line breaking.